# html2pdf not working with jpeg images

Tags: pdf, report, jpeg, html2pdf

i am working on user profile reports but got problem when having a photo with .jpg extension but png working perfect using **HTML2PDF** & when i paste the link in browser it shows photo. any suggestion or solution please , thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just one step more.

You can convert all your .jpeg file to .png files using 
[Here you can convert all your .jpeg to .png](http://convertio.co/jpg-png/)

Comment: thanks for quick response, as i m getting data using php and i can not restrict my user to upload only png or convert it first